# Php session needs to be refresh to get the latest session value from angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, session

I created a session in php and the value of that session is from angularjs. I created a function that has a parameter. And every time I click on a button, the function will execute and the parameter of the function will send to php.  What my problem is when I click the first button my php page will display the value of `18` and it is correct. Now when I go back to the buttons and click another then redirect to php page it doesn't echo the new value which is `20` and it still echo the last value which is `18`.

```
$scope.sendval = function(id){
    $http.post('page',{
        'param': id
     }).then(function(response){
         //some codes...
     });
};
```

page.php

```
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$_SESSION['param'] = $data->param;
```

Display session

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['param'];
```

My problem is the value of the session remains the same. But when I refresh page, it updates. How to do it without page refresh? TIA!

What I've already tried and still not working:

```
session_destroy($_SESSION['param']);
// and
unset($_SESSION['param']);
$_SESSION['param'];
```

Comment: you can use  session_unset(); or
    session_destroy(); function .

Comment: I already did that sir. But still not working

Comment: Anyone help me?! @RokiDGupta

Answer (score 0):

You must have placed the unset in the wrong place.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if (isset($_SESSION['param'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['param']);
    $_SESSION['param'] = $data->param; 
}
else{
    $_SESSION['param'] = $data->param; 
}
?>
```